# How to copy a cell across a dynamic range of columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have data on a large number of rows 200000+ and 20 columns or less that I would like to graph. Because it is so large graphing becomes problematic. I would like to copy every nth row to a new sheet and graph from the new sheet.

I can accomplish the task by entering and dragging offset formula.I would like to do this same task dynamically with VBA code. In this code I am trying to enter offset formula into cell a1 of sheet2 and copy the formula to a range defined by data range on sheet1. It gives error "autofill method of range class failed" on last line.

```
Sub copy_5()

Dim startCol As String
Dim startRow As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastCol As Long
Dim myCol As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")
startCol = "a"
startRow = 1
lastRow = ws.Range(startCol & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastCol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
myCol = GetColumnLetter(lastCol)

Set rng = ws.Range(startCol & startRow & ":" & myCol & lastRow)

For Each cell In rng

Next cell


    With ActiveWorkbook
    .Sheets.Add(after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = "sheet2"
    End With

    Range("a1").Value = ("=OFFSET(data!A1,(ROW()-1)*5,0)")

    Range("a1").AutoFill Destination:=Range(startCol & startRow & ":" & myCol & lastRow)


End Sub
```

It gives error

> "autofill method of range class failed"

on last line.

I would like it to fill the same number of columns in sheet2 as are in sheet1.

Comment: You want to copy every 5th row? If so, use a `Union` and `For i = 2 to LR Step 5` while adding your increments to the `Union`

Comment: Thank you Union worked great! I had tried copy, autofill, and other functions with only partial success.